# Connecting to hosted MS SQL DB with PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

The front end of my website runs on PHP.  It is hosted on a shared hosting platform run by Verio.  The back end is a MS SQL database which is also hosted Verio's platform.

Verio which was recently bought by Endurance International Group Hldgs Inc (EIG).  My site's files were migrated automatically to EIG's servers.  The connection to the MS SQL database broke when that happened.

One of the files on my website is a settings.php file.  Prior to Verio's migration to Endurance's servers, the connection string I used for the 'DB_SERVER' global variable in that settings.php file was '198.170.241.132,1433\SQLExpress1'  That box is going offline soon and my site has been migrated so I need to connect to a database on the new servers.

I've been able to create a MS SQL database on Endurance's servers through their web portal. However Endurance support tell me they can't give out an IP address for the server the database is hosted on. I'm trying to figure out how I would connect to the server without an IP address.

The file settings.php on my website contains  connection info which I tried to update to the following (being the details of the database I set up through the new web portal) to see if it would work.  It did not work:

```
$GLOBALS['DB_DATABASE']='mydbnamegoeshere';
$GLOBALS['DB_SERVER']='VCNSQL102';
$GLOBALS['DB_USERNAME']='myusernamegoeshere';
$GLOBALS['DB_PASSWORD']='mypasswordgoeshere';
$GLOBALS['DB_VENDOR']='MSSQL';
```

There is a knowledgebase article on Verio's site discussing how to connect to the servers, however it is written for ASP.NET websites, not PHP sites.  Furthermore it does not specify the IP of the server that MS SQL databases are hosted on.  The knowledgebase article is here: http://www.verio.com/knowledgebase/beta/article.bml?ArticleID=1829

Any suggestions on the correct settings to use (and where to put them) would be most welcome.

Comment: "can't give out an IP address"? well - either they give you a DNS-name instead or you should look for another hoster on grounds of incompetence. either way, this is a topic you have to *completely* handle with your hoster, not with a *coding* community.

Comment: Thanks Franz.  Next guy who has a similar issue now knows that he needs an IP address or DNS name because of the first part of your comment.  Isn't sharing information what the coding community is about? So was the second part necessary?

Comment: yeah - but sharing *relevant* information. the quirks of *one* hosting service is too specialised to be of use to more than a hand full of people, and as i said - a topic best to handle with the hoster, not with programmers. and unless your question is about the *code* you are hosting instead of the hoster, i'm afraid it is off-topic for SO, and so are requests to *configure* instead of *debug* your code. especially if the necessary credentials are, and should, only known to you.

Answer (score 0):

A freelancer helped me to get this working so while I don't profess to be an expert, I don't want to be a DenverCoder9 (or a Franz) so I'll share what I do know in case some of the 5 million+ EIG customers have similar issues (or others on similar shared hosting platforms that have crappy support and don't give out the IP of their hosted MS SQL DBs):

1. .htaccess in the root folder needed to be rewritten with pointers to the subfolder that is root for the site in question. The relevant code for the site that uses the MS SQL db (the code for which is in a subfolder of the root directory of my site because it runs as a subdomain) is:

RewriteEngine on

```
### subdomain redirect v3 ###
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?subdomainurl.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomainfoldername/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomainfoldername/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?subdomainurl.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subdomainfoldername/$1 [L]
```

2. The PHP file that contained connection settings was modified to add

   define ('DF', '\subdomainfolder');   // here the subdomain folder is defined for appending to $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] for path construction to the folder, where the original site is 
   $GLOBALS['APPLICATION_DIR']=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].DF;
   $GLOBALS['APPLICATION_CLASSES_DIR']=$GLOBALS['APPLICATION_DIR'].'\classes\';
   $GLOBALS['APPLICATION_FORMS_DIR']=$GLOBALS['APPLICATION_DIR'].'\forms\';
   $GLOBALS['APPLICATION_SKINS_DIR']=$GLOBALS['APPLICATION_DIR'].'\skins\';
   $GLOBALS['APPLICATION_USER_FILES_DIR']=$GLOBALS['APPLICATION_DIR'].'\userFiles\'; 
   $GLOBALS['APPLICATION_HELP_FILES_DIR']=$GLOBALS['APPLICATION_DIR'].'\helpFiles\';
3. The following was added for connecting to the database (new sessions directory settings)
   session_save_path($GLOBALS['APPLICATION_DIR'].'\session\');

   $GLOBALS['DB_DATABASE']='mydbnamegoeshere';
   $GLOBALS['DB_SERVER']='VCNSQL102,1433\I102'; //Server, port # and instance for DB.  Note there's no IP needed which is what I was confused about in my original question
   $GLOBALS['DB_USERNAME']='mydbusernamegoeshere';
   $GLOBALS['DB_PASSWORD']='mydbpasswordgoeshere!';
   $GLOBALS['DB_VENDOR']='MSSQL';
4. This line in the index.php file that users land on when they visit the site was commented out (because save path is set in the new code added in #3 above):

   session_save_path("/home/users/web/b1234/apo.username/cgi-bin/tmp");